# Phonegap barcodescanner plugin: use font camera option

Tags: ios, cordova, camera

I've managed to make my app use the front camera via [this website](http://michaelehead.com/post/20038040089/defaulting-to-front-facing-camera-on-ipad-with-phonegap).
By changing the code I can decide which camera the app will use.
I want my users to make that decision though, so I'm looking for a way to implement this... For example by putting a checkbox on index.html or by putting a button on the scanning-screen which swaps the camera. 
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

I would be very thankful...